# Firestore adapter to get all users documents but just not current user document to display in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am using Cloud Firestore as my database to save all users as documents in 'users' collection. I want to display all the users in 'users' collection into my `RecyclerView` except the current user who is currently using the app. I searched a lot to find a solution all over the internet but could not find any. So please help me out guys and thanks in advance. I'm a beginner, so really need your help. And thanks again.

This is my Firestore adapter:

```
mQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users");
                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<NearbyUserRecyclerModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<NearbyUserRecyclerModel>()
                            .setQuery(mQuery,NearbyUserRecyclerModel.class)
                            .setLifecycleOwner(getActivity())
                            .build();

                    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<NearbyUserRecyclerModel,NearbyProfilesViewHolder>(options) {
                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NearbyProfilesViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final NearbyUserRecyclerModel model) {
                            holder.itemBuddyState.setText("0");

                            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(model.getThumb_pictures()).into(holder.itemImage);

                            holder.itemDisplayName.setText(model.getFirst_name());

                            holder.itemOnline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position);
                            if (snapshot.contains("online")){
                                Boolean onlineState = snapshot.getBoolean("online");

                                if (onlineState == true){
                                    holder.itemOnline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                else {
                                    holder.itemOnline.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            }

                            final String user_id = snapshot.getId();

                            mChatRequestCollection.document(current_user_id).collection("request_received")
                                    .document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(),
                                    new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                                if (document.contains("received_time")){

                                                    holder.itemBuddyState.setText("3");

                                                }else {
                                                    Log.d("REQUEST RECEIVED", "onComplete: received field doest exist, "+task.getException());
                                                }

                                            }else {
                                                Log.d("REQUEST RECEIVED", "onComplete: Document doesn't exist, "+ task.getException());
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });

                            mChatRequestCollection.document(current_user_id).collection("request_sent")
                                    .document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(),
                                    new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                                                if (document.contains("sent_time")){

                                                    holder.itemBuddyState.setText("2");

                                                }else {
                                                    Log.d("REQUEST SENT", "onComplete: sent field doesn't exist, "+ task.getException());
                                                }

                                            }else {
                                                Log.d("REQUEST SENT", "onComplete: Document doesn't exist,");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                            mChatHolderCollection.document(current_user_id+"/user_chats/"+user_id)
                                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(),
                                    new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                                if (document.contains("timestamp")){

                                                    holder.itemBuddyState.setText("1");

                                                }else {
                                                    Log.d("CHAT_HOLDERDOC", "onComplete: timeStamp field doesn't exist, "+task.getException());
                                                }

                                            }else {
                                                Log.d("CHAT_HOLDERDOC", "onComplete: chat buddy doesn't exist, "+task.getException());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                            holder.itemImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    userPopupDialog(model, user_id);
                                    //  popupIntent(user_id);
                                }
                            });

                            holder.itemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final View v) {

                                    String message = holder.itemEditText.getText().toString();

                                    if (holder.itemBuddyState.getText().equals("0")){

                                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {

                                            WriteBatch request_batch = mRootStore.batch();

                                            Map<String, Object> sentMap = new HashMap<>();
                                            sentMap.put("sent_time", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                                            sentMap.put("message", message);

                                            Map<String, Object> receivedMap = new HashMap<>();
                                            receivedMap.put("received_time", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                                            receivedMap.put("message", message);

                                            Map<String, Object> notificationMap = new HashMap<>();
                                            notificationMap.put("from", current_user_id);
                                            notificationMap.put("type", "request");

                                            DocumentReference sentRef = mRootStore.collection("chat_requests").document(current_user_id + "/request_sent/" + user_id);
                                            request_batch.set(sentRef, sentMap, SetOptions.merge());

                                            DocumentReference receivedRef = mRootStore.collection("chat_requests").document(user_id + "/request_received/" + current_user_id);
                                            request_batch.set(receivedRef, receivedMap, SetOptions.merge());

                                            DocumentReference notificationRef = mRootStore.collection("users/" + user_id + "/notifications").document();
                                            request_batch.set(notificationRef, notificationMap, SetOptions.merge());

                                            request_batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                        //------------Request Sent------------//
                                                        holder.itemEditText.setText("");

                                                        holder.itemBuddyState.setText("2");

                                                        Log.d("REQUEST_LOG", "onComplete: Request sent Successfully");
                                                        Log.d("REQUEST_LOG", "onComplete: Notification sent Successfully");

                                                        Snackbar.make(v, "Request sent Successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    } else {
                                                        Snackbar.make(v, "Failed Sending Request", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                        Log.d("REQUEST_LOG", "onComplete: Failed sending request" + task.getException());


                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }

                                    }

                                    if (holder.itemBuddyState.getText().equals("3")){
                                        holder.itemEditText.setText("");
                                        Snackbar.make(v, "Request already received by user", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                    if (holder.itemBuddyState.getText().equals("2")){
                                        holder.itemEditText.setText("");
                                        Snackbar.make(v, "Request already sent", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                    if (holder.itemBuddyState.getText().equals("1")){
                                        holder.itemEditText.setText("");
                                        Snackbar.make(v,"User already chat buddy", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public NearbyProfilesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.nearby_profiles_recycler_items, parent, false);

                            final AppCompatImageButton button_send = view.findViewById(R.id.itemSendButton_id);
                            final AppCompatEditText editText_message =  view.findViewById(R.id.itemEditText_id);

                            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_send_new);
                            drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                            DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTabUnselected));
                            button_send.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                            button_send.setEnabled(false);

                            editText_message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                                @Override
                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                    String message = editText_message.getText().toString();

                                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
                                        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_send_new);
                                        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                                        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTabUnselected));

                                        button_send.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                                        button_send.setEnabled(false);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_send_new);
                                        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                                        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTabSelected));

                                        button_send.setImageDrawable(drawable);

                                        button_send.setEnabled(true);
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                                }
                            });

                            return new NearbyProfilesViewHolder(view);
                        }
                    };

                    nearbyRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in which you can query a Firestore database using `!=` (not equal to operator). So the following line of code does not exist:

> Query query = db.collection("users").where**Not**EqualTo("userID", userID);

In this case, you need to create your own logic for that. To solve this, you need to query your database for all users but the adapter should receive all of them except one, the current user. So you need to create an if statement to check if the current user is different than the others.

Comment: thanks a lot alex for correcting my question and also telling me that firestore-UI doesn't provide this service and i need to create my own adapter with my own logic. at least now i won't be wasting anymore time searching for an answer that doesn't exist.

Comment: i accepted your anwer. thanks again. hope to resolve some more issues from you  in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Change the IF condition in the below method

```
 public void getUserData(){
    db.collection("users")
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    if(document.getData().get("userID").equals(userID)){
                       // User user = (User)document.getData();
                       // Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: "+user.getUserName()+ user.getDescription() + user.isGender());
                        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                        user.put("name", document.getData().get("name"));
                        user.put("userID", document.getData().get("userID"));
                        user.put("email", document.getData().get("email"));
                        user.put("companyName",document.getData().get("companyName"));
                        user.put("officeAddress", document.getData().get("officeAddress"));
                        user.put("phoneNumber", document.getData().get("phoneNumber"));
                        user.put("gender",document.getData().get("gender"));
                        user.put("isProfileComplete",document.getData().get("isProfileComplete"));
                        user.put("profilePicUrl", document.getData().get("profilePicUrl"));
                        user.put("description", document.getData().get("description"));

                       /* if(document.getData().get("isProfileComplete")){
                            LoginActivity loginActivity = (LoginActivity)mContext;
                            loginActivity.navigateToHome();
                        }else{
                             LoginActivity loginActivity = (LoginActivity)mContext;
                            loginActivity.navigateToHome();
                        }*/
                       boolean check = (Boolean) document.getData().get("isProfileComplete");

                       if(check){
                           LoginActivity loginActivity = (LoginActivity)mContext;
                           loginActivity.navigateToHome();
                       }else{
                           LoginActivity loginActivity = (LoginActivity)mContext;
                           loginActivity.navigateToOnBoarding();
                       }

                        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete:GET DADA "+ user.get("isProfileComplete"));
                    }else{
                        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete:ID "+document.getData().get("userID") );
                        LoginActivity loginActivity = (LoginActivity)mContext;
                        loginActivity.navigateToOnBoarding();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate and just to be clear here i need to define my own adapter instead of using firestore ui adapter.

Comment: Yup! We have to first parse the document.getData() values to hashmap and then we can populate the adapter by passing the hasmap to it